# Phonegap/Cordova App to connect a api

Tags: api, cordova

I have a simple REST API made in Rails with output data in json format. 
I want create a phonegap app to connect and consume the API resources. someone know a tutorial to do this.

I am only a junior backend dev and no know about mobile apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget, i found this [Cordova Tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/) that use [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: While it's encouraged to answer your own question, it's best to avoid link only answers and provide the gist of the link into your answer content.